# Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map between affine varieties, that pulls back germs of regular functions to regular functions. Then $f$ is a morphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

More precisely, we have that $\forall\ \alpha\in X, \phi\in \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(\alpha)}$, we have $f^{*}\phi\in\mathcal{O}_{X,\alpha}$, so that $f^{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(\alpha)}\subseteq\mathcal{O}_{X,\alpha}$.

I know that for any open set $U$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U):=\bigcap_{\alpha\in U}\mathcal{O}_{X,\alpha}$ and similarly, $\mathcal{O}_Y(V)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in V}\mathcal{O}_{Y,\alpha}$, and I must prove that $f^{*}\mathcal{O}_Y(U)\subseteq\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))\ \forall\ \mathrm{open\ sets\ } U\in Y$.

Now, what I have so far is that $$f^{*}\mathcal{O}_Y(U)=f^{*}\bigcap_{\alpha\in U}\mathcal{O}_{Y,\alpha}\subseteq\bigcap_{\alpha\in U} f^{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y,\alpha}$$If $f$ was surjective, then I could do the following:
$$\bigcap_{\alpha\in U} f^{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y,\alpha}=\bigcap_{\alpha\in f^{-1}(U)} f^{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(\alpha)}\subseteq\bigcap_{\alpha\in f^{-1}(U)}\mathcal{O}_{X,\alpha}=\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))$$ and the proof would go through. But what if $f$ is not surjective? Does the statement still hold?

Definitions: Working over an algebraically closed field $k$ we define $\mathbb{A}^n$ to be the set of all $n$-tuples of elements of $k$, and we consider $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n$ to be an *affine variety* if for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $X=Z(\mathfrak{p})$, the zero-set of $\mathfrak{p}$. This makes $X$ irreducible as a topological space.

Comment: What exactly are your affine varieties? Schemes, irreducible algebraic subsets of k^n? Do you have a ground field, is it algebraically closed?

Comment: I added some definitions.

Comment: Hint: Contemplate the pullbacks of the coordinate functions $Y\to k$.